# Program a WebFlux-based SSE-client with reconnect-features

Tags: java, client, flux, spring-webflux, server-sent-events

I'm developing an SSE-client using WebFlux. What I want to achieve is to setup the client in a way, that

1. it automatically reconnects to the SSE-server, if the SSE-server was temporarily not available
2. it can also connect during run time, in case the SSE-server wasn't present from the start.

However, as far as I understand JavaScript-based clients, they are basically able to fulfill (1) and (2).

My question: is there a way to  configure a WebFlux client to show the desired behaviors (1) and (2) (ideally "declaratively" via a builder and fluent coding style)? - I didn't find any information on how to do this, however, I assume that those are standard requirements for an SSE-client.

Here the basic code I'm using for my tests:

```
        final SslContext sslContext
                = SslContextBuilder
                .forClient()
                .trustManager(InsecureTrustManagerFactory.INSTANCE)
                .build();
        final HttpClient httpClient
                = HttpClient
                .create()
                .secure(t -> t.sslContext(sslContext));
        final WebClient client
                = WebClient
                .builder()
                .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient))
                .build();
        final ParameterizedTypeReference<ServerSentEvent<String>> type  = new ParameterizedTypeReference<ServerSentEvent<String>>() {};

        final Flux<ServerSentEvent<String>> eventStream
                = client.get()
                .uri(endpointURL)
                .exchange()
                .flatMapMany(it -> it.bodyToFlux(type))
                .repeat();

        eventStream
            .subscribe(
                this::updateInformation
                , error -> LOGGER.error("Error - {}", error.getMessage())
                , () -> LOGGER.info("Got event stream completion signal."));
```